# C++ Pointers/Arrays(I'm completely and utterly confused at this moment and really need help)

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

So This Is What I Ended up coming up with for it. I currently can't figure out how to put my reverseArray function into the main... If i just copy and paste the code into it, it crashes every time it's run... I don't know why it causes it to crash or anything. Thank you everyone that has helped me so far with this.

```
using namespace std;

// Prototype for printArray goes here
void reverseArray(int*, int);
void printArray(int*, int);

int main()
{
    int size;   // size of the dynamically allocated array

                // Declare as needed for a dynamically allocated array of 
ints named "data".

            // Declare other variables as needed


            // Edit to display your own name
cout << "" << endl << endl;

// Prompt the user for the array size
cout << "Array size: ";
cin >> size;

// Add code to validate array size, so it is greater than one
while (size < 2)
{
    cout << "Array size must be greater than 1: ";
    cin >> size;
}

// Add code to dynamically allocate "data". Don't forget to release the memory before
// the program ends
int *data = new int[size],
    *p = data;
// Write a loop to fill the "data" array with random numbers from 1 - 100 (inclusive)
// This code must use POINTER NOTATION (no subscripting) to work with the array.
// Reminder: neither of these notations is acceptable here:
// data[n]  or *(data + n)
// Instead this code will use pointer incrementing/decrementing and dereferencing

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, p++)
{
    *p = rand() % 100 + 1;
}
// Call function to print the original "data" array
cout << "\nOriginal array:\n" << endl;
printArray(data, size);
// Reset "data" to point to the beginning of the array 

// Add code to reverse the array. Use 2 pointers: one starts at the beginning of the array and
// moves forward, the other starts at its last element and works backward. Swap the values they
// point to.
// Reminder: neither of these notations is acceptable here:
// data[n]  or *(data + n)
// Instead this code will use pointer incrementing/decrementing and dereferencing
// For this, I made the function reverseArray instead of coding it in main.
reverseArray(data, size);
cout << endl;
cout << "\nReversed array:\n" << endl;
printArray(data, size);
cout << endl << endl;
// Finish up
delete[] data;
system("pause");
return 0;
}

// Function printArray() goes here. Print the array, 5 numbers per line, 
right-aligned
void printArray(int*p, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++, p++)
    {
        cout << setw(5) << right << *p;
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
// Function reverseArray() Reverses the array.
void reverseArray(int *data, int size)
{
    int *e = data + size - 1;      // Pointer at the end
    for (; e > data; data++, e--) // while end pointer (e)> start pointer, swap start w/ end
    {
        int arrayFlip = *data;
        *data = *e;
        *e = arrayFlip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointers take a bit of brain-wrapping. Best advice for just about any case where pointers come into play and bring confusion is to draw pictures.

Comment: *"I personally hate c++ and I think its a really ass backwards language"* Ha! :P

Comment: Well, no point my editing that out now. Ah smurf it. Killing it anyway.

Comment: lmao sorry for being honest XD

Comment: Back to the point, can you name any *specific* questions that you have? I'm not sure how to help you. The google is full of pointer tutorials, and maybe we could make another small one just for you, but it would be better if you told us what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Just read through your code. Doesn't look like you're having any trouble with the pointer allocation/deallocation, that's where most folks realize they <expletive deleted>ed up. Do you know how to use a pointer to iterate through an array?

Comment: Ok, specifically here " // Reset "data" to point to the beginning of the array". I understand what's happening when it how the array is created with the pointer (the pointer is now at the "end" of the array) and now that it's at the end, it needs to be reset at the beginning of the array. Is there a way to reset it to the beginning of the array so my printArray function correctly prints out the array like it does in in the lines before the "array" is put into the function?

Comment: A pointer is simply a variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. For example, while `int a = 5;` stores the immediate value `5` as its value, `int *b;` creates a pointer to `int`, and `b = &a;` stores the address of `a` (the memory address where `5` is currectly stored) as its value. If you need the value stored at the memory address pointed to by a pointer, you *dereference* the pointer using the unary `'*'` operator. To reset a pointer, simply assign a new address to the pointer.

Comment: I just done understand how I would get the pointer to return to the start of the array because the way I see whats happening is that the pointer is at the final value and when the function is called, its printing out the last number, then x amount of numbers (based on the size variable) are printed and they print out "-842150451"

Comment: Do you know how to reverse an array using the disallowed `[]` syntax, so that you can work up to pointers from there?

Comment: i mean, i could show you everything that was in there before that I added and all she put. All she put was int size, the cout of the name, the cout of the array size, and the cout that says original array and reversed array. Every single thing else is what I put there lmao.

Comment: Oh, I thought this was all instructor-provided code (good comments, I guess?).  Sorry!

Comment: lmao np :P She tells us to comment the <expletive> out of it basically XD

Comment: When possible, prefer to name variables and functions so that you don't have to leave comments except when things get really ugly. Easiest way to reset a pointer is to keep a copy of the original value. So `int*reset = data;` move `data` around (`data++;`, `data--;`) to your heart's content, and when you want to reset, `data = reset;`

Comment: I understand that, but where would I be putting something like that so that when i use the printArray function, it would start at the original value and not the last value?

Comment: The relationship between arrays and pointers can be confusing. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) is the best explanation I know of. (Most of it applies to C++ as well as to C.)

Comment: _"Like I said, I've been using google and searching through here and I cant find anything on it."_ That's why you're having so much trouble. You can't learn a powerful language like C++ in this manner. Which book do you have?

Answer (score 3):

You may be torturing yourself for no reason, or beating your head into a brick wall (don't worry - we've all been there... and have the bruises to prove it.)

First, lets start with any allocated block of memory, say:

```
     int *a = new int[NELEM], ...
```

What is `a`? (a pointer -- yes, but to what?) It is a pointer to the beginning address in a block of memory, `NELEM * sizeof *a` bytes in size. What type of pointer is it? (`int`). How many bytes per-int? (generally `4`).

So why is having the pointer be type `int` important? (well, it sets the type-size that controls how pointer-arithmetic operates when referencing the block of memory though that pointer) Meaning since your pointer type is `int`, the compiler knows that `a + 1` is `a + 4-bytes` which allows you to reference the next value in your block of memory.

OK, but I allocated memory for `a`, what are my responsibilities with regard to `a`? In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

What does that mean to me? It means that if you cannot simply increment `a` (e.g. `a++`) in the scope where `a` was declared. If you do, you have lost your reference to the beginning address of the block and that block can no longer be freed (that's a *memory leak*).

So if I cannot use any indexing (e.g. `a[i]` or `*(a + i)`) and I can't increment my pointer `a` -- then what are my options? *Use another pointer...*, e.g.

```
    int *a = new int[NELEM],
        *p = a;
    ...
    std::cout << "array  : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++, p++) {
        *p = rand() % 100 + 1;
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << *p;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
```

Have you satisfied your responsibilities regarding the block of memory you assigned to `a`? Sure, `a` still points to the beginning address of the block, so it can be freed. All you did was use a second pointer `p` and iterated using `p` leaving `a` unchanged.

Hmm.. Using a second pointer.. I wonder if I can reverse my array using that same scheme. Yep. In it simplest form, you could do something like:

```
 void rev (int *a, size_t size)
{
    int *e = a + size - 1;      /* end pointer */

    for (; e > a; a++, e--) {   /* while end > start, swap start, end */
        int tmp = *a;
        *a = *e;
        *e = tmp;
    }
}
```

But wait!! You said you couldn't increment `a` without losing the starting address to my allocated block -- how can I `free` it now? (`a` in `main()` never changes, the function `rev` receives a copy of `a` and within `rev` you are free to increment/decrement or do whatever you like to `a`, within the bounds of the block of memory, because `a` in `rev` has its very own (and very different) address from your original pointer in `main()`.

(an aside...) You could have declared a third pointer within `rev`, e.g.

```
    int *s = a,                 /* start pointer */
        *e = a + size - 1;      /* end pointer */
```

and then used `s` instead of `a` in your iteration and swap, but there isn't any need to. You are free to do it that way if it is more clear to you which pointer you are working with. It's simply another 8-bytes (or 4 on x86), so the additional storage is a non-issue.

Putting it altogether in a short example, you could do something similar to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

#define NELEM 10

void rev (int *a, size_t size)
{
    int *e = a + size - 1;      /* end pointer */

    for (; e > a; a++, e--) {   /* while end > start, swap start, end */
        int tmp = *a;
        *a = *e;
        *e = tmp;
    }
}

int main (void) {

    int *a = new int[NELEM],
        *p = a;

    srand (20180502);

    std::cout << "array  : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++, p++) {
        *p = rand() % 100 + 1;
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << *p;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    rev (a, NELEM);
    p = a;
    std::cout << "reverse: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++, p++)
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << *p;
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete[] a;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_reverse
array  :    11    6   78   93   25   71   82   58   97   68
reverse:    68   97   58   82   71   25   93   78    6   11
```

All of this takes a bit of time to sink in. We all have bruises on our foreheads from the same wall. Just make peace with the fact that a pointer is just a variable that holds the *address of* something else as it value (e.g. it points to where something else is stored).

Understand how the `type` of the pointer effects the pointer-arithmetic (and indexing), e.g. how many bytes are advanced with `p++` or in `for (i = 0; i < size; i++) p[i]`, and make sure you know exactly where your pointer is pointing and things should start to fall into place.

If you ever have any problems figuring out what is going on with your pointer, pull out an 8.5 x 11 sheet of paper and a No.2 pencil and just draw it out -- on each iteration fill in the block where your pointer is pointing, etc.. -- it really helps. Once you have drawn enough diagrams, done enough linked-lists, stacks, etc... you won't need the paper as much as you do now (you will still need it -- so keep it handy)

---

**Reversing in `main()` with a Function**

In response to your comment, when you look at `main()`, you already have an additional pointer `p` declared. So you can simply use that as your start pointer and add `e` from from the `rev()` function as your end-pointer. A simple implementation would be:

```
int main (void) {

    int *a = new int[NELEM],
        *p = a,
        *e = a + NELEM - 1;;

    srand (20180502);

    std::cout << "array  : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++, p++) {
        *p = rand() % 100 + 1;
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << *p;
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    p = a;                      /* reset pointer */
    for (; e > p; p++, e--) {   /* reverse array */
        int tmp = *p;
        *p = *e;
        *e = tmp;    
    }
    p = a;                      /* reset pointer -- again */
    std::cout << "reverse: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < NELEM; i++, p++)
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << *p;
    std::cout << '\n';

    delete[] a;
}
```

(same output)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: so mostly from what you got, I could get a semi working function. So thank you so much for that! With that being said, I can't figure out how tf to put the cose from reverseArray into my main ( it would be before the second printArray funtion). Again thank you for the assistance so far.

Comment: If you move the `rev` code into `main()` you WILL need to use an additional pointer because you can't increment `a` in `main()`. So use the version with `s` (for start) I note above. You can pretty much move the `rev` code into `main()` where I call `rev (a, NELEM)`. Just make sure you replace `a` in the function with `s` you will declare as `int *s = a;`

Comment: See the additional edit showing how you would move `rev` into `main()` using your existing `p` as the start-pointer, and declaring `e` in `main()` as your end pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines in `main`  are not correct.

```
*data = rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << setw(5) << right << *data;
```

They just set the value of the first element of the array and print the same element.

Use `data[i]` instead.

```
data[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << setw(5) << right << data[i];
```

If you must use the pointer notation, use `*(data+i)`.

```
*(data+i) = rand() % 100 + 1;
cout << setw(5) << right << *(data+i);
```

Another method you can use is to use a temporary pointer variable just for iterating over the array.

```
int* iter = data;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++. ++iter)
{
    *iter = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << setw(5) << right << *iter;

    ...
}
```

This makes sure that you don't lose the original pointer, which is necessary to be able to deallocate the memory.

**PS** There may be other errors, or not, but I noticed the above problem after a quick glance through your code.

Comment: We cant use "array notation" and we specifically need to use "pointer notation" (whetever that means (it works when it does what you put and thats how I originally did it as well)

Comment: I do completely and utterly agree that what you have is the correct way to do it but she was saying it wasnt.

Comment: this is why I'm running into this issue in total.

Comment: she still considers data+i array notation as seen here: 
 This code must use POINTER NOTATION (no subscripting) to work with the array.
 // Reminder: neither of these notations is acceptable here:
 // data[n]  or *(data + n)

Comment: if i could do it that way, i would have been done this hours ago.

Answer (score 1):

## Moving A Pointer

```
data++;
```

and

```
data--;
```

mostly. There are other things you could do, but your instructor asked for increment and decrement.

So

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *data = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << setw(5) << right << *data;
    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

becomes

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *data = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << setw(5) << right << *data++; // change made here
    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Note only one `data++`, and it's on the second use of `data`. You should be able to figure out why.

## Resetting A Pointer

The easiest and most obvious is to

```
int*reset = data;
```

then you can `data` around to your heart's content, and when you want to reset,

```
data = reset;
```

So the above loops wind up looking like

```
int*reset = data; 
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    *data = rand() % 100 + 1;
    cout << setw(5) << right << *data++; // change made here
    if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
data = reset;
```

But... You can also separate your logic out into functions and take advantage of pass by value

```
void fill(int * data,
          int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        *data = rand() % 100 + 1;
        cout << setw(5) << right << *data++; // change made here
        if ((i + 1) % 5 == 0)
        {
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

and the related part of `main` now looks something like

```
data = new int[size];
// Write a loop to fill the "data" array with random numbers from 1 - 100 (inclusive)
// This code must use POINTER NOTATION (no subscripting) to work with the array.
// Reminder: neither of these notations is acceptable here:
// data[n]  or *(data + n)
// Instead this code will use pointer incrementing/decrementing and dereferencing
cout << "This is just the test to see if the pointer is successfully creating the array" << endl;
fill(data, size);
// Reset "data" to point to the beginning of the array
```

"Just wait a minute!" you're thinking. "How in Crom's name is `int * data` pass by value? That's a <expletive deleted>ing pointer!" The data pointed **at** is passed by reference, but the pointer itself is passed by value. `data` in fill is a copy of `data` in `main`. All of the `data++`ing in `fill` happens to a copy, so `data` in `main` is still pointing right where you left it.

No reset required **and** you've simplified `main`'s responsibilities by spinning off part of them to their own simple and independently testable function. Keeping everything as simple, small, and stupid as possible is worth it's weight in bitcoin in my view.

Comment: So where you put "change made here" was just me outputting the data. I get that. Now that should be done in the function "PrintArray". This is where I'm finding an issue. I don't get how I would loop it in the function "printArray" so that it does all the values and doesn't only print the last value then 22 other values (when putting 23 for the size). We're supposed to do something where she commented " // Reset "data" to point to the beginning of the array " which is what confuses me. I understand how to create the array but also understand that somehow the pointer needs to go back to

Comment: I'm a huge believer in not relying on people to understand the precedence of operators. So I would prefer `*(data++)` to make it painfully clear that the pointer is being incremented, and not the pointed to integer (as would be the case in `(*data)++`

Comment: beginning of the array and show each value that was made in the loop.

Comment: @DiabolicNick what I think your instructor is guiding you towards is iterator-based functions, where you pass an iterator (pointer) to the start and an iterator (pointer) to the end, and the function operates on each value, incrementing the iterator until it is equal to the end value

Comment: @jwm Yes, i believe that is what would happen, but I'm lost as to how I would go and do that. I dont get how I would get a pointer at the start to read the array and/or how I would set it up that its reading the array. For example, we're supposed to put 23 for the value and get the array of 23. I get that having two different pointers (one at the start and end) would accomplish this and to do the reverse, I would just have to simply reverse them, but again, I dont understand how I would tell the pointer to do that outside of a loop.

Comment: `int* data = new int[size];` declares a pointer (`data`) and assigns it the value of the allocated memory. `int* startPtr = data;` declares another pointer (`startPtr`) and assigns it the same value, the address of the first element in the array. You now have two pointers with the same value. `int* endPtr = data + size -1;` declares a pointer (`endPtr`) and assigns it a value that points to the last element in the array. What if you increment one until it reaches the other, or decrement the other until it reaches the first? Can you see how you might reverse the order?

Comment: @DiabolicNick I didn't touch `printArray` because it's already doing what it needs to do. All you need to do is make sure the `data` is pointing to the right spot after filling the array, and I provided two strategies to do this. I also didn't touch reversing the array. That one is a different question.